# pandas replicating and editing 'n' rows based on values from two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

Considering the following dataframe `df` below:

```
from numpy import nan
import pandas as pd
d = {'x': {0: 'MT', 1: 'MT', 2: 'MT', 3: 'MT', 4: 'MT', 3379: 'MT', 3406: 'MT', 4184: 'MT', 4248: 'MT'}, 'Position': {0: 3, 1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 6, 3379: 568, 3406: 573, 4184: 16184, 4248: 16193}, 'Reference': {0: 'T', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'C', 4: 'C', 3379: 'C', 3406: 'C', 4184: 'C', 4248: 'C'}, 'Variant': {0: 'C', 1: 'G', 2: 'C', 3: 'T', 4: 'G', 3379: 'C', 3406: 'C', 4184: 'C', 4248: 'C'}, 'Min': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 3379: 2.0, 3406: 2.0, 4184: 2.0, 4248: 2.0}, 'Max': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 3379: 8.0, 3406: 8.0, 4184: 5.0, 4248: 3.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

We see that under the columns `Min` and `Max` I have `NaN` as well as floats. Eventually what I am trying to do is to replicate the letters under `Variant` n times, whereas the number that this letter will be replicated is dictated by the values under `Min` and `Max`

Wherever there is a `NaN` under `Min` or `Max`, the observations under `Variant` should remain unchanged.

For each of the rows in which there is a float under `Min` or `Max` I shall replicate the rows under them n times, where n equals `Max` - `Min`.

After replicating the columns, I shall edit the observations under `Variant` according to the values specified by `Min` and `Max`.

For example, considering the row of index 3379, I shall replicate this column 8 - 2 = 6 times, such that I will have a total of seven identical rows. Now I should 'enlarge' or concaenate the obsevations under `Variant` n times, from `Min` to `Max`, such that, considering this row (or index 3379), my replications would look like the following:

```
d1 = {'x':{3379: 'MT', 3380:'MT', 3381:'MT', 3382:'MT', 3383:'MT', 3384:'MT', 3385:'MT'}, 
      'Position':{3379:568, 3380:568, 3381:568, 3382:568, 3383:568, 3384:568, 3385:568},
      'Reference':{3379:'C', 3380:'C', 3381:'C', 3382:'C', 3383:'C', 3384:'C', 3385:'C'},
      'Variant':{3379:'CC', 3380:'CCC', 3381:'CCCC', 3382:'CCCCC', 3383:'CCCCCC', 3384:'CCCCCCC', 3385:'CCCCCCCC'},
      'Min':{3379:2.0, 3380:2.0, 3381:2.0, 3382:2.0, 3383:2.0, 3384:2.0, 3385:2.0},
      'Max':{3379:8.0, 3380:8.0, 3381:8.0, 3382:8.0, 3383:8.0, 3384:8.0, 3385:8.0}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

I would like to do this for all rows in which the observations under `Min` and `Max` are not `NaNs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, using default constructor and `np.repeat`

```
n = (df['Max'] - df['Min'] + 1).fillna(1).astype(int)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({c: df[c].values.repeat(n, axis=0) for c in df.columns}, 
                   index=df.index.repeat(n))

m = df[['Min', 'Max']].notnull().all(1)
df2.loc[m, 'Variant'] = df2.loc[m, 'Variant'] * df2.loc[m].groupby(df2.loc[m].index).cumcount().add(2)

        x       Position   Reference    Variant     Min Max
0       MT      3          T                  C     NaN NaN
1       MT      5          A                  G     NaN NaN
2       MT      5          A                  C     NaN NaN
3       MT      6          C                  T     NaN NaN
4       MT      6          C                  G     NaN NaN
3379    MT      568        C                 CC     2.0 8.0
3379    MT      568        C                CCC     2.0 8.0
3379    MT      568        C               CCCC     2.0 8.0
3379    MT      568        C              CCCCC     2.0 8.0
3379    MT      568        C             CCCCCC     2.0 8.0
3379    MT      568        C            CCCCCCC     2.0 8.0
3379    MT      568        C           CCCCCCCC     2.0 8.0
```

Comment: Very close, the only thing is that your code is replicating (the 'C') from one to seven whereas I want to replicate from two to eight i.e. between the values specified under `Min` and `Max`

Comment: I was about to fo thru your code to check where I could do that. Anyway, you got the answer faster, thanks very much

Comment: @BCArg I have edited the code to suit this ! take a look ;)